# bug in connection to cluster mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i'm using nodejs to connect to mongodb and i get this error
i added the IP and nothing happend

```
(node:7412) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to cluster0-shard-00-02-xobf0.mongodb.net:27017 closed
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\NodeJS - The Complete Guide\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:352:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at _handle.close (net.js:597:12)
    at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:388:7)
(node:7412) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7412) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

Comment: you are using `mlab` for `mongodb` connection? if yes, show your code for better understading

Comment: non i'm using mongodb atlas

Comment: show your connection code for mongodb.

Comment: const mongoConnect = (callback)=>{
  MongoClient.connect('mongodb+srv://youssef2:YtO9le2ryPzvIi4J@cluster0-wnoho.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true').then(client =>{
  console.log("connected!");
  _db = client.db();
  callback();
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
  throw err;
});
};

Comment: i just found a dummy way that i delete my IP then i return it so  it works but after a few minutes it returns

Comment: check the answer i posted @youssef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ,

```
 const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
 const uri ="mongodb+srv://user:userpassword@meanapp-srlw9.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true";
 const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
 client.connect(err => {
 const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
 // perform actions on the collection object
   console.log("connencted");
 client.close();
});
```

For now, change your cluster setting to connect from anywhere